# Registration in Russia during 2 year study stay

Tags: student-visa, study, rental, russia, german-citizens

I (German citizen) will study in Russia for 2 years. Is there a registration in a governmental office (e.g. embassy, police office, ..) required after entering the country with a study visa? Also, what documents are necessary (possibly copy of the rental agreement)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, the inviting party (in this case the university) will register you in the place of residence. It is important to contact the responsible migration office in the university max. 3 business days after arriving. Required documents are your passport, visa and migration card that was handed to you at the border. Foreign students are registered either in a student dormitory or at the address of the university itself, in case they chose to privately rent an apartment. The rent contract etc is not necessary to show.

In return, you will need to pick up the registration (a document stating some information about you which includes your registration address) and keep it. Police can ask to see these documents (passport, migration card, visa and registration) at any time.